# java inheritance cannot find symbol

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation

I have this line in my class:

`public class Line extends Figure` and when I compile with this command:

`$ javac -cp :./stdlib.jar Line.java`, I get this error:

`Line.java:26: cannot find symbol`
`symbol  : constructor Figure()`
`location: class Figure`
`public Line(double x0, double y0, double xn, double yn, Color initColor) {`
`-------------------------------------------------------------------------^`
`// the dashes above are supposed to be spaces, but I couldn't figure out how to format it correctly. The caret is actually there in that position`

Normally I would understand this error, but this time I have no idea what is going on. I have the `Figure.java` file in the same directory as my `Line.java`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is there is no empty (default) constructor in Figure. Your Line has a constructor which takes several parameters. Line extends Figure. If you don't call a specific constructor in the super class in the constructor for Line, Java will attempt to call the default (no param) constructor, but Figure doesn't have one, so you get a compilation error.

In the constructor for Line, you'll need something like:

```
public Line(double x0, double y0, ...) {
    super(x0, y0);
    ...
}
```